# Prove homotopy of maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying for a qualifying exam and I am having difficulty on the following problem and I don't really know how to begin.  Any help would be great.

Let $M, N$ be compact manifolds and for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$   $f_t
: M \rightarrow N$
a continuous map. Suppose that there is $f : M \rightarrow N$ continuous with
$f(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} f_t(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in M$. Prove that for all sufficiently large
$t$ and $s$ the maps $f_t$ and $f_s$ are homotopic.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use the uniform convergence of $f_t \rightarrow f$, or is that not necessary?

Comment: On second thought, the homotopy equivalence classes of continuous maps $M \rightarrow N$ are open in the uniform topology, so uniform convergence makes this problem somewhat uninteresting.